# iPhone iOS UIImage how to detect a "laser pointer" dot on a camera feed?

Tags: computer-vision

I got a tracked robot toy and I'm controlling it with an iPhone. The robot outputs a live camera feed of a known frame size and I'm displaying it on UIImage.

I've added a laser pointer to the robot and fixed it alongside the axis of the robot. I'm trying to detect the laser pointer dot on the image and thus try to calculate the proximity of the object. If the laser dot is far away from the center, I know that the robot is stuck against the wall and needs to back up.

**How can I go about detecting a dot of bright white-red pixels on a screen?** One solution would be to sample the color of pixels within a certain radius of the center and detect a blob bright color. Can anyone suggest an algorithm for this activity?

Another approach would be to keep track of the average position of the dot over the last few frames, thus reducing the guesstimate radius. If there's no dot within a pre-defined region, the search region may be expanded.

Finally, I want to be able to teach the robot to detect carpet around it. Carpet reflects a laser pointer in a certain way, and I want to understand how many frames around the robot have similar properties. If I know where the laser pointer is at a screen, I can clip a small rectangle from that image and compare them one to another. Is there an efficient way of comparing multiple small images to one another to understand if their silhouettes match?

I noticed that the laser is reflected off glossy surfaces, and the direction of this reflection may tell me something about the orientation of the surface in space, in accordance with the laws of refraction.

Thank you!

[image: Laser Pointer close]

[image: Laser pointer 1]

Comment: Can you turn the laser pointer on and off in a pattern?  Like one frame it's off, the next it's on, and you subtract subsequent frames to make it very obvious.

Comment: That's a very good idea! But I don't have control over the laser pointer, its either on or off.

Comment: @AlexStone I am trying to achieve similar thing, the only difference is I am trying to detect the laser light on eye pupil. Can you help me with the ios code or any sample code that you sued with opencv in tracking the laser beam ? Appreciate your help in advance, thanks AJ.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

[OpenCV](http://www.eosgarden.com/en/opensource/opencv-ios/overview/) is compilable for iOS. While it may not be the most efficient it gives you the option of porting the algorithm. I have done a similar marker tracking problem using the ConDensation algorithm. Look up marker tracking with OpenCV. It is a VERY large research area and the exact algorithm you want depends completely on your application. If I remember correctly there are around 3000 reported image processing techniques - to pick a good one is a real art!

> One solution would be to sample the color of pixels within a certain
>   radius of the center and detect a blob bright color. Can anyone
>   suggest an algorithm for this activity?

By the way, this is the basic idea behind what is called a particle filter (of which Condensation is one method). Well done you figured out the basic idea by your self!

> Another approach would be to keep track of the average position of the
>   dot over the last few frames, thus reducing the guesstimate radius. If
>   there's no dot within a pre-defined region, the search region may be
>   expanded.

This is called state persistance and can be modelled in various ways. The condensation algorithm uses a stochastic approach not dissimilar to a plain old Kalman filter.

> Is there an efficient way of comparing multiple small images to one
>   another to understand if their silhouettes match?

This one is a little more difficult. You could try template matching but I don't know how well it will perform on iOS (very heavy calculation and iOS camera is not well suited to it).

Comment: Paul, thank you for an incredibly detailed answer! I got OpenCV framework, and will look for examples of projects using it.

Comment: Hi Paul, Do you have any idea on the sample app for laser detection via iOS camera using openCV ?

Answer (score 0):

How about this code

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MKUWnz_obqQ

https://github.com/niitsuma/detect_laser_pointer

In this code HSV color are compared using hotelling's t square test